# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Error When Using Firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui

When I install Firebase using Pods I get this error:

```
    GoogleUtilities.framework: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I tried restarting my computer, going into keychain and unlocking and relocking, and using pop deintegrate. It runs perfectly fine when I remove the pod completely. It is strange as I created a new project with SwiftUI and it installs and runs perfectly fine.

I am trying to test the app in the simulator and it is a SwiftUI app. Thank you

Update: I also tried downgrading a version and I still get the same error.

I installed an older Xcode and still get the same error

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Sometimes, just restarting Xcode helps. You might also want to try `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install`.